# How can I remove owner permission on space in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco-share

I wrote the below code to remove permissions:

```
locationSpace.removePermission("Consumer");
locationSpace.removePermission("Collaborator");                     
locationSpace.removePermission("Coordinator");
locationSpace.removePermission("SiteManager");
```

Its working fine, but it's working only when that folder is created by another user.
The user that creates that folder is the owner of that folder, so the owner permission doesn't get removed.

I want to remove the owner's permission and I want to give consumer permissions to the owner.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: are you creating this space via rule or webscript or how?

Comment: i am creating it through js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways ode doing this.

1. Use the setOwner again but use the admin user. So you're basically moving the ownership to admin.
2. Use the delete method to remove a property.

delete node.properties["cm:owner"];
node.save();

Answer (score 1):

You could play with permission definitions and set up "owner" definition per your needs. In that case you would not remove it, since it would actually hold the "consumer" permission you want.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/secur-permissions.html

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/script-remove-control-document

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/deny-delete-permision-owner